# Why do I see ttyUSB2 on nmcli, not see wwan0?

Tags: modem, networkmanager

I want to use NetworkManager to control wwan0. But I only see ttyUSB2 in NetworkManager device list.

I use "cat" command to make ttyUSB2 & ttyUSB3 in use, but it doesn't work.

The below is modemmanager info

```
root@imx6qsabresd:~# mmcli -m 0

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id '74d82342f71de5945dddcc381409e231f5ed5df1')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'SIMCOM INCORPORATED'
           |          model: 'SIMCOM_SIM7600JC-H'
           |       revision: 'LE11B01SIM7600JC-H'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts, lte'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts, lte'
           |   equipment id: '861478030131862'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/soc0/soc/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1'
           |        drivers: 'option1, simcom_wwan'
           |         plugin: 'SimTech'
           |   primary port: 'ttyUSB2'
           |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (at), ttyUSB3 (at), wwan0 (net)'
  -------------------------
  Numbers  |           own : 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'unknown'
           |          state: 'registered'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'unknown'
           | signal quality: '80' (recent)
  -------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none'
           |        current: 'allowed: any; preferred: none'
  -------------------------
  Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
           |        current: 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  IP       |      supported: 'ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6'
  -------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: '861478030131862'
           |  enabled locks: 'none'
           |    operator id: '46692'
           |  operator name: 'Chunghwa Telecom'
           |   subscription: 'unknown'
           |   registration: 'home'
  -------------------------
  SIM      |           path: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0'

  -------------------------
  Bearers  |          paths: 'none'
```

Does anyone know how to make wwan0 appear in NetworkManager device list?

Answer (score 0):

You see ttyUSB2 in NetworkManager because that is the "primary port" reported by ModemManager in the modem details.

In this specific case, ModemManager doesn't know how to use the WWAN port of the device (exposed by the non-standard `simcom_wwan` kernel driver), and therefore it will fallback to use PPP over a TTY port.

If you want to use the WWAN port with NM/MM you **must not** install the `simcom_wwan` kernel driver, and instead, you should just use the standard `qmi_wwan` kernel driver. Once you do that, you'll get a `cdc-wdm` port (that speaks QMI) and an associated WWAN port (in raw-ip mode), and those are nicely used by ModemManager/NetworkManager.

If you ask me, there should be no reason to use the `simcom_wwan` kernel driver by normal users. If your `qmi_wwan` driver doesn't expose the QMI ports of the modem, you may just need a newer kernel.

Comment: this is really insightful. yet: effectively this means the issue is that NetworkManager does not know how to work with a PPP over TTY connection?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. NM works fine with PPP over TTY. The problem here is that if ModemManager doesn't know how to manage the wwan interface, it will fallback to PPP over TTY, which is not optimal. Either way, NetworkManager will get the info of what to use, and will setup the connection accordingly. If MM says PPP should be used, NM will use PPP over a TTY. If MM says static IP addressing or DHCP should be used, NM will use static IP addressing or DHCP over a wwan interface.